# URLs in comments bugs

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

When commenting, and you write a URL in backticks, the `http://www.` part is cut off, and it is converted to a link. Converting it to a link might not be so bad, but cutting it off can change the meaning of the content as you usually put code in backticks.

I also accidentally came across a bug; there seems to be something strange going on with the characters after the URL. See my comments to this post. I entered the following in backticks:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/user/home.php");
```

#### Not completed!

See more bugs in comments to this question.

Comment: See example: `header("Location: http://www.example.com/user/home.php");`

Comment: There's also something funky going on with that semi-colon. I entered it as `header(...);` and I even tried removing the comment and re-adding it to make sure it wasn't an error on my side.

Comment: On a related (faintly related) subject: how do you get backticks to appear in text embedded in backticks?

Comment: try using backslash like \`ticks\` versus un back-slashed `ticks`

Comment: Seeing if bug is still here: header("Location: http://www.example.com/user/home.php");

Comment: Another bug: http://beta.multifarce.com/api/get_frame?frame=7001 note that that URL actually ends after "7001", yet its text ends with "7001/..."

Comment: URL's in comments- You so crazy!!!

Comment: `header("Location: http&#58;//example.com/user/home.php";);`

Comment: header("Location: http://‎www.example.com/user/home.php");

Comment: Codified version: `header("Location: http://‎www.example.com/user/home.php");`

Answer (score 6):

Ok this is now fixed; placing comment urls inside a code `` block makes them immune from being link-ified.

Comment: not inside code block: http://www.example.com inside code block: `http://www.example.com`

Comment: Awesome! =) The two other URL bugs still remain though: header("Location: http://www.example.com/user/home.php");   and   http://beta.multifarce.com/api/get_frame?frame=7001

Comment: URL #1: semi-colon after `"` should not be there. URL #2: trailing `/...` should not be there.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, to get the link to show in its entirety within the comments, you'll have to include some [Unicode character that has no width](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/how-do-i-write-a-url-in-a-comment-without-making-it-a-link/24728#24728), like a [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), that will be taken out by the parser and breaks the URL at the same time.

```
header("Location: http://‏​www.example.com/user/home.php");
```

Which kind of looks like this:

```
header("Location: http://<hidden unicode>www.example.com/user/home.php");
```

Anybody with over 100 pastalicious rep points can just hit the edit and see what's being hidden in the "broken" URL for the comment.

To type the zero-width space: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>8207</kbd> (This may not work on all systems. See a detailed description for Windows [here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).)

Comment: `ALT + 8207` got me a beautiful ☼

Comment: @smeagol What keyboard are you using?

Comment: @random: a beautiful Generic brand, Spanish distribution, 101 or 102 Compatible keyboard in Spanish setting on Windows 2000. This happens regardless of the set Language. I'm getting the feeling that it has something to do with the system really working with `latin-1` instead of `Unicode`.

Comment: I also got a ☼.

Comment: What is the latin version of the zero-width space?