# How do I write a URL in a comment without making it a link?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, markdown

I tried to add a comment that included this text:

```
https://username@password:www.mysite.com/mypath/
```

But it showed up like this:

[username@password:www.mysite.com/mypath/](https://username@password:www.mysite.com/mypath/)

How can I prevent auto-hyperlinking in a comment?

**The magic: (view edit (not source))**

```
https://‎username@password:example.com/mypath/
```

Comment: Like this: https://‎username@password:www.mysite.com/mypath/ ?

Comment: Yes.  Please post whatever you did as an answer.

Comment: @Stein Go into edit mode for your question and check out what's been added.

Comment: like this? `https://username@password:www.mysite.com/mypath/` -- just put it in a code block delimited by \`

Comment: We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the code `` delimiters

Comment: Thanks, but that *must* be new.  It hadn't worked before when I tried it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508391/how-to-run-net-exe-using-cron-job-on-cloud-server/1511034#1511034 (I had to add the space to get it to work.)

Answer (score 7):

The examples above use U+200E Left-to-Right Mark as a zero-width joining character to break up a sequence that would be spotted as a link otherwise. This is a bit dodgy IMO; directionality characters have a specific use and this isn't it. Although U+200E isn't one of the directionality characters described by W3/Unicode as [discouraged for use in markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/#Charlist), there is an argument for stripping them out, as the ‘discouraged’ characters definitely should be.

I suggest U+200D [Zero-Width Joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) instead. (Although, in practice I tend to use U+200B Zero-Width Space, since [my keyboard](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/win/eurokb.html) makes it easy to type.)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to include some Unicode character that will be taken out by the parser and breaks the URL at the same time.

```
https://‎username@password:example.com/mypath/
```

Which kind of looks like this:

```
https://<hidden unicode here>username@password:example.com/mypath/
```

Comment: Ok, trying that:  http<b>:</b>//this.is@test.com

Comment: As you can see, that didn't work.

Comment: Trying the edited answer:  https://‎username@password:example.com/mypath/

Comment: So, besides copying your answer, how does one create a hidden character?

Comment: Take the surnames of your two creators and reverse them. Then chroma map one of the other characters and you've now created Noob Saibot. Or just use this: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm

Comment: Or use https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm instead of https://‍fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm, as recommended in the [answer of bobince](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24728/493669). Tip: [this](https://unicode-table.com/en/200D/) site has a nice "copy" button that allows you to copy the Unicode character to your clipboard :-)