# Don't process URLs as links inside code blocks

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I write a URL in a comment without making it a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/how-do-i-write-a-url-in-a-comment-without-making-it-a-link)

If I include a URL within backticks in a comment, it should not be processed as a link.  It appears to work properly for questions, but when I include a url inside backticks in a comment, the url gets changed into a link (which shouldn't happen).  For example, see my comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658070).  I'll also add a comment to this question demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Now if I add a comment for this using backticks, I get this:  `NSURL * u = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];`

Comment: Notice how the `http://` has been removed from the text and replaced with a link.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/how-do-i-write-a-url-in-a-comment-without-making-it-a-link

Comment: thanks for the dupe link, but having to resort to typing hidden unicode characters to get a url to display properly is an epic FAIL in usability.

Comment: @Dave: that's only the workaround, not the solution. Well, hopefully...