# Bug: backticks don't stop link recognition in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I write a URL in a comment without making it a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/how-do-i-write-a-url-in-a-comment-without-making-it-a-link)
>   [URLs in comments bugs.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/urls-in-comments-bugs)

So for instance, the following doesn't work: `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>`, it recognises the rather poor link of `http://google.com">Google</a>` and links to that and mangles the HTML that you probably intended to display too.

Comment: So that there is an example on the same page: `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: declined as 'duplicate'