# URLs in comments are truncated if they contain certain punctuation characters

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, hyperlinks, auto-linking

I just tried to paste this URL in a comment:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)

but it comes out like this (note the trailing `"...)"` is no longer included):

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)

Since the `.` and `)` *are* part of the URL, they should be parsed as such.

This happens in questions and answers too, but in Q&A backslash escapes can be used as a workaround.  In comments they cannot.

---

Loosely related: [URLs in comments bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/urls-in-comments-bugs)

However in this case I **do** want the URL to be linkified.  The URL is valid but is incorrectly being truncated.

Comment: Try some of the techniques here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses

Comment: @Jon Seigel, yes I often use that workaround when linking to javadocs from answers.  Sadly it does not work for comments.

Comment: The second technique at [Jon's reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses/13509#13509), [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) the reserved parentheses, `#asList%28int...%29`, makes the parser understand the non-reserved dots as well: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29

Comment: Oh, this is an old question. Maybe it even works without percent-encoding nowadays, but I doubt that: http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to encode the parens, or do it in an answer where there is more comprehensive linking support.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perennial problem with autolinking, and there's no one good answer. It's quite common to have trailing punctuation that isn't part of the URL (so I can do things like this, linking to http://www.example.com/...). In my experience (albeit on a non-technical forum), trimming the trailing characters fixes more comments than it breaks.

One way forward that works well for me is to count `)` as a trailing-character-to-remove only if there's a `(` character earlier in the URL. Don't know if that's feasible for how the comment linker works though.

Comment: I don't buy that argument.  It's like having the spell checker in MS Word forcibly changing "escapade" to "escaped" without the option to disable it, just because the latter is more frequently used.  Your URL is wrong (actually it's valid, because the trailing dots are part of the URL, but the URL you entered is not the one you intended.) and correct URLs shouldn't be made impossible to enter just so that some incorrect ones can be auto-corrected.

Comment: In principle I agree, but the reality is not trimming the ends breaks a lot of links that normal users type. It's not impossible to enter URLs ending with `.` using the extended syntax in comments... it's just unfortunate that `)` is used as the delimiter in this syntax so you can't have it in a URL at all.